# Setting up a collaborative environment for web application development

Tags: magento, web, development-environment

My office is growing and ive been tasked to build out the IT for our web development.

Whats the best tool/setup for doing web development in a group setting? The requirements are a centralized code repository, a location to test development code on, and finally a way to push tagged code out to a staging server. What im thinking is svn/redmine for code repo, each user has an account on a central development machine to allow for ssh access(eclipse over ssh) and their own virtual host on the dev server which gives everyone a centralized development sandbox. Code is written and tested on this dev box then checked back into svn and later tagged and pushed out to the staging server. Yeah? Thoughts comments or recommendations?

*Also, in a dev environment what is the best way to handle databases? Is it wise to pull from the production database? Also should each developer have his/her own db or work off a master db?

**We are building a magento application and also have some custom backoffice tools that run on cakePHP.

Comment: If you're still interested, this is an answer I wrote similar to what you're asking about database syncing - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005406/how-to-safely-deploy-stage-database-to-live-production-database-in-magento/9013523#9013523

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this subject is off-topic in StackOverflow and flagged so then you need to concentrate on following areas:

VERSION-CONTROL

- GIT has all the glory and you don't need your own box for this as https://bitbucket.org/ offers unlimited data and private/public repos and you can set your codebase there. http://github.com is also powerful and de facto most popular version-control oriented tool out there although it comes for a small price
- so your master branches live in your version control and your devs will checkout frpom there and commit to it as well
- your deployment tools will deploy data to your live and staging environments from your master

ENVIRONMENTS

- usually three are used LIVE, STAGE, DEV
- LIVE is well live and only approved code gets deployed there
- STAGE is pre-live environment and should be exact replica environment according to LIVE so all things can be tested there by merchant
- DEV is cool to have exact replica but can as well be on developers local env and is ment for loose testing and experimenting

DATABASES AND DEPLOYMENT

- mysql databases are pain in the ass to sync so you better have a script for it that syncs from live to others and prevent syncing from other environments to LIVE. This limitation also requires that all the configuration and content will be added from LIVE only and only then synced down the line. Every change to schema or permanent setting should be handled by update scripts (As we are talking MAGENTO CE , MAGENTO EE has migration built in)
- for deployment I also suggest you to build a fabric or capistrano script that resets dev and staging environments, handles database reset and pull from LIVE DB, and imports code from central repository.

it's also a good idea to target the following everyday tasks:

- clients needs to reset the stage for it's tests
- project manager, developer or testers need to test so spawning a test clone should be oneclick action (take current db and code and make it live in some subfolder for specific test only) as well as deleting the test
- 3rd party devs might need access to specific test or dev environment (this is actual with magento as in average there are at least 10 external extensions installed in every magento store)